# how do i run jenkins process with user permission

Tags: jenkins

I created a batch file to run with Jenkins process, 
When I run it in the CMD in the PC it runs fine, 
but when I run it with the Jenkins as a flow, it's stuck, as you can see:

```
"Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TARD Testing\workspace
No emails were triggered.
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson5135873889105585615.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TARD Testing\workspace>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Buildscripts 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Buildscripts>call DAR.bat 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Buildscripts>ן»¿echo off 
'ן»¿echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Buildscripts>C:\\EZcheck_ENV\\EZcheck_1_00\\test_engine.pyc
"C:\\EZcheck_ENV\\project\\login_script_dart.csv"
"C:\\Users\\alpha\\AppData\\Roaming\\DaRT\\results\\test_uzi_1.rst" 
"C:\\Users\\alpha\\AppData\\Roaming\\DaRT\\variables" 
"C:\\Users\\alpha\\AppData\\Roaming\\DaRT\\reports"
"C:\\Users\\alpha\\AppData\\Roaming\\DaRT\\temp" master
```

Someone told me that it's because I need to run the Jenkins process with user permissions, 
Do you know how I do that or if that's even the problem..?

Comment: "It's stuck, as you can see" — we can't really see that; you'd have to add more verbose output to your test suite to show if and where it's hanging.

Comment: Did you try to protect your path against spaces?

Comment: Dear Christopher Orr thank you for your answer, the prossec stuck, you right i didnt write it's well..but, the flow manualy run few min. but in the Jenkinse it's stuck, till i aborted the flow/prossec.
do you have any Idiea? 

Thank you Dear Bruno Lavit, can you please axplain me how do i do that?